# Cookie size and performance?

Tags: asp.net, performance, .net-core, cookies, azure-active-directory

I am working on an Asp.Net core web app that is using Azure AD Authentication. The .Net library for adding AD authentication is adding **8kb** of cookie for Jwt tokens. We are experiencing some slowness in the web app, and one of the areas we are looking into is the size of the cookies.

Is **8kb** of **cookie** too large that may cause **performance** issues?

Answer (score 1):

While 8kb is on the large side when it comes to cookies, I would not look to this as a main cause of performance issues.

Cookies are brought down in the headers of the web request that is made, and are not processed in any special way until they are used on the client-side (in this case, to handle authentication).

This web page, for example, made 28 requests for me in Firefox on a fresh load, and 45 in Chrome (Firefox blocked more). And transferred 872KB in less than a second and a half. Let's say that cookies took up 8kb (in this case, it was much less). If I could cut that in half, then we would have 4kb less to transfer, which might save a very negligible amount of time (a millisecond or two?).

Of course, every web page and client is different, and things will also vary based on your location, which cdn you use, and what your connection speed is. But I would be shocked if the size of the cookie by itself was the cause of your performance issue.

More likely are the other resources you are bringing down, long-running scripts that hold up page load, etc (it is very hard to say without any more insights into what else is happening).